# JSONObject issue A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at

Tags: java, json, exception, jsonexception

So Im trying to use this json file, but when I try to parse it with JSONobject it gives me the error. I tried finding similar issues but it seemed that ppl didnt have the same thing.

The code produce this error msg

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: 
        A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

Java:

```
public void readSubjects(String filename){
    obj =new JSONObject(filename.trim());
    objArr=obj.getJSONArray("subjects".trim());
    String tmpName;
    String tmpRealName;
    for(int i=0;i<objArr.length();i++){
        tmpName=objArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("subject_code");
        tmpRealName=objArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
        System.out.println(tmpName + " " + tmpRealName);
    }
}
```

JSON-file:

```
{
    "teachers": [
        {
            "name": [
                "Peremann"
            ],
            "age": 22,
            "subject": [
                "pgr200"
            ],
            "availability": true,
            "contact_info": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Jarand",
            "age": 23,
            "subject": "root"
        }
    ],
    "subjects": [
        {
            "subject_code": "pgr200",
            "name": "Avansert Javaprogrammering",
            "campus_priority": "Fjerdingen",
            "educationForm": "",
            "subjectProgram": "",
            "duration": "X",
            "amountOfHours": "",
            "amountOfStudents": 12
        }
    ],
    "studentGroups": [
        {
            "students": []
        }
    ],
    "rooms": [
        {
            "room_code": "F11",
            "fasilitetsstoette": "test",
            "max-capasity": 50,
            "room-size": "X"
        }
    ]}
```

Comment: [The first stop should always be the documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#pubctors) What does it say about the `JSONObject(String)` constructor? (Separately: `"subjects".trim()`? Huh?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As far as I can see, JSONObject expects a string literal, not a filename (so it won't read the file, you have to do that separately)

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
obj =new JSONObject(filename.trim());
```

is incorrect. The [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)) of `JSONObject` expects an actual JSON string, **not** the name of a file.

First read the content of the file and then pass it along to `JSONObject`'s constructor.

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("example.json")));
obj = new JSONObject(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked [Samebug](https://samebug.io/searches/8916670) for you to see if any of our users have had a simular issue. They've come back with the following recommendations.

> The json is invalid or you try to map to a different model
>
> Replace single quotes (') to double ones ("). You should use double quotes in JSON.

I also found a [Github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/testrail-plugin/issues/24#issuecomment-316047442) comment that may be useful.